# Adding own objects in createMuiTheme

Tags: material-ui, themes

Is it possible add custom objects to the "createMuiTheme"?
Lets say I have a cart icon in the AppBar, can I some how inject this so that it is available in the "createMuiTheme"?

Something like this:

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
    custom: {
        CartIcon: {
            color: "#333"
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes. a custom object can be added in MUI theme object.
You've added the custom `CartIcon` color in the object, now you can access that object inside the `makeStyles` in this way:-

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    cartClass:{
      color:theme.custom.CartIcon.color;
    }
}));
```